# Matplotlib Table Row Label Font Color and Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Given the following table:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
table=plt.table(cellText=[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], # rows of data values
          rowLabels=['1','2','3','4','5'],
          cellLoc="left",
          rowLoc='left',
          bbox=[0,0,.2,1], # [left,bottom,width,height]
          edges="")
```

[image]

I'd like to change the color of the numbers (1-5) to grey and the font size to 12 point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get text font properties of the cells:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
table=plt.table(cellText=[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], #rows of data values
          rowLabels=['1','2','3','4','5'],
          cellLoc="left",
          rowLoc='left',
          bbox=[0,0,.2,1],#[left,bottom,width,height]
          edges="")

# iterate through cells of a table
table_props = table.properties()
table_cells = table_props['child_artists']
for cell in table_cells: 
        cell.get_text().set_fontsize(20)
        cell.get_text().set_color('grey')
plt.show()
```

Another method to get text properties of the cell is used cell indexes (i, j):

```
table[(i, j)].get_text().set_fontsize(12)
table[(i, j)].get_text().set_color('red')
```

Matplotlib text font properties are described here: http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontproperties

As a result, the first code draw this figure:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Stanley. What if my table is an axis (i.e. ax1.table(cellText....)? When I try it that way and use ax1.properties() instead of table.properties(), I get "KeyError: 'child_artists'"

Comment: Not an every `matpoltlib` object has a §child_artists§ method.

Comment: @DanceParty2: Should still work. In other words, `table = ax[1].table(cellText...)` and then `table.properties()`. I can't guarantee that this will work with every version of Matplotlib, but it works with v1.3.1.

Comment: I found the child cells under 'children' and not 'child_artists'

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments of the question I modified the code to `table_cells = table.properties().get('child_artists') or table.properties()['children']` and it worked.